# How do I *PREVENT* a Windows batch file from executing in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

On Windows in Eclipse, when I double click on a batch file name in navigator, or even a repo browser, the batch file opens in a command window and is executed.

How do I make the *default* double-click behavior to open in an editor instead?

Note that I can select "open in text editor", but if I choose "open in system editor", that too causes it to execute.

I honestly googled for this, but only found "how to run", and no explanations of "how NOT to run".  I can't imagine this hasn't been asked before, but I couldn't figure out the incantation.

[Editorial comment:  there are *tons* of references describing how *to* run a batch file, implying its difficult to do or figure out.  Its odd that mine appears to behave that way out of the box.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Preferences and go to 'General > Editors > File Associations'.

If there is an association in the list for *.bat change the association to be 'Text Editor'.

If there is no association change the setting for 'open unassociated file' at the bottom of the preference page to be 'Text Editor'. Alternatively, if you don't want to change the 'no association' setting, add a new file association for *.bat

Note that if you have used 'Open With' on a file that choice is remembered and used in future.

Comment: Perfect!  It appears deleting the association falls back to "text".  Oddly, "unassociated" was set to "search marketplace", which it didn't do.